# Power BI filter based on subtotals?

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset that looks roughly like this:

| Project | Resource | Department | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Dwight | Sales | 2 |
| C | Jim | Sales | 4 |
| A | Creed | Quality | 1 |
| B | Jim | Sales | 3 |
| D | Creed | Quality | 2 |
| D | Michael | Corporate | 8 |

I want to filter based on the projects with or without hours billed to the Quality department.  So in this case I want to filter two set of data - all Projects C & B (nothing Creed screwed up)  or all projects A & D (where Creed "checked").

I have a SQL background and this would be dead simple with a JOIN - still figuring out the structure as I am new to Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two **Measures** similar to:

```
Project count w/ Quality = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(YourTable[Project])),
    YourTable[Department] = "Quality" && YourTable[Hours] > 0
  )


Project count w/o Quality = 
  var result = COUNTROWS( DISTINCT(YourTable[Project]) ) - [Project count w/ Quality]
  return IF(result <> 0, result)
```

You can use these measures in visuals, and/or as visual filters depending on your need.

[image]

Comment: This works as detailed; however, you can't filter or slice based on this.  You can filter that table example - I need to filter other visuals etc.

Comment: You should be able to. Update your question with an example scenario that you are needing. If possible, share a link to a sample PBIX.

Comment: It's odd - I ended up just creating the first measure.  If that is > 0 then I should be able to filter by < 0.  If I add a data table with project and the measure I only get the subset.  If I try and add the measure to a filter or slicer it won't allow it.  Will try and get a sample uploaded.